# Can I connect to Memgraph database using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, memgraphdb

Can I connect to the Memgraph database using JavaScript? Do I need to install some server-side components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that you need is a running Memgraph instance. There are no additional components, or severe tweaking needed to connect using JavaScript. All that you need is to just modify this code so that it has all of the correct server parameters in it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Javascript Browser Example | Memgraph</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/neo4j-driver"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Check console for Cypher query outputs...</p>
    <script>
      const driver = neo4j.driver(
        "bolt://localhost:7687",
        neo4j.auth.basic("", "")
      );

      (async function main() {
        const session = driver.session();

        try {
          await session.run("MATCH (n) DETACH DELETE n;");
          console.log("Database cleared.");

          await session.run("CREATE (alice:Person {name: 'Alice', age: 22});");
          console.log("Record created.");

          const result = await session.run("MATCH (n) RETURN n;");

          console.log("Record matched.");
          const alice = result.records[0].get("n");
          const label = alice.labels[0];
          const name = alice.properties["name"];
          const age = alice.properties["age"];

          if (label != "Person" || name != "Alice" || age != 22) {
            console.error("Data doesn't match.");
          }

          console.log("Label: " + label);
          console.log("Name: " + name);
          console.log("Age: " + age);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        } finally {
          session.close();
        }

        driver.close();
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The official documentation can be found at https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/connect-to-memgraph/drivers/javascript.